# Out-gridview filter wildcard

Tags: filter, wildcard, out-gridview

Just wanted to confirm, from my observation, the FILTER in out-gridview can't accept wildcards, is that correct? I tried *, %...it doesn't seem to support any and I can't find documentation that confirms this.

For example I have :

[image]

If I filter with this there are no results found:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, turns out it was staring me in the face.

Just a SPACE character acts as a classic wildcard.

For example:

SQL SP2

is like if you were filtering with

SQL*SP2

A bit surprising, but it works :)

[image]